# NASM Difference between CMP and OR

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I got 2 questions. The first one: what is the difference between 'or' and 'cmp'? I have seen both, and it seems like they do the same thing. My second question: what does

```
or al, al
```

mean? Should it not return true all the time (like x == x)?

Comment: Related [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806) - `test al,al` is architecturally equivalent but better on modern CPUs (can macro-fuse with JCC and doesn't write a partial register).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually, assembly doesn't work as simply as `return true`. Generally speaking, conditional execution is usually based on a status register. I will use Intel x86 architecture in this explanation. Note that other architectures are different, but the basic principle stays as far as I know.

As mentioned before, the flow of the program is determined by status register, named `FLAGS` on x86 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLAGS_register). As you can see there is for example `ZF` (zero flag) bit. In case when conditional instruction such as `jz` or `jnz` is executed, the `ZF` is checked and the jump is executed (or not) based on this state.

The `FLAGS` register is updated as the code is being executed, each instruction setting some (sometimes none) bits to appropriate values. This data can be read in appropriate manuals for the given architecture. On x86 for example, `add` instruction alters `CF` (carry flag).

If you look up `or` instruction, it updates `FLAGS` like this: "The OF and CF flags are cleared; the SF, ZF, and PF flags are set according to the result." (http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf#G5.251049).

Therefore, the

```
or al, al
```

code's functionality is based on whatever conditional instruction follows. It has no meaning standing alone as `x |= x` (in C-like languages) has basically no effect on the value but has a side-effect on the status register.

From what we could read, we could for example use

```
or al, al
jnz _someWhere
```

in order to decide whether the contents of `al` register are nonzero and in case it is, jump to `_someWhere`.

For an explanation of reasoning for using `test al, al` instead of `cmp al, 0` or `or al,al` (all of which set FLAGS identically), I suggest reading Peter Cordes' excellent writeup at [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33721204/test-whether-a-register-is-zero-with-cmp-reg-0-vs-or-reg-reg/33724806#33724806)

Comment: `and al, x` isn't as fast as `test al,x` in some cases, e.g. on AMD CPUs, or Intel Core2 / Nehalem, where `test` can macro-fuse with a JCC but `and` can't.  See [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806).

Comment: `or al,al` / `test al,al` are both architecturally equivalent to `cmp al, 0`.  OR and AND both write all FLAGS; they set CF=OF=0, not leave it unmodified, just like `cmp`.  There is no partial-flag problem, or any interaction with P4's false FLAGS dependency for `inc`/`dec`; P4's `inc` will have a false dep on `or al,al` just like `test al,al` or `cmp al,al`.  Modern CPUs handle inc/dec and other instruction that only interact with CF by renaming CF separately from the SPAZO set of flags.  See [INC instruction vs ADD 1: Does it matter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36510095)

Comment: @PeterCordes sorry for the late update, I have changed the answer to give just the basic explanation and link to your answer.